# The fast way to select the elements in a list which a property is in another list

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, list

I have a class Like this,

```
class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a List ids;

I want to select all the elements in List which its ID is in the list ids. My current solution like this:

```
var v = from t in tests where ids.Contains(t.ID) select t;
```

If the count of List is very large, more than 10000 items, is it a effective way?

Thanks

Comment: How large is large? How many elements are in the list? Have you already measured the performance in some way?

Comment: If you have a list, then you will always have to check all entries, with O(n) no matter what. Only thing that could be faster is some sort of dictionary or map with O(1) access.

Comment: If you sort both lists by id, the search can then be done linear. But a dictionary would be even faster of course.

Comment: the elements in the list are more than 10000, I didn't do any performance test yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var lookup = ids.ToDictionary(x => x);
var matching = tests.Where(t => lookup.ContainsKey(t.ID));
```

That will work provided that `ids` does NOT contain any duplicate values.

Or (faster, as per comments below):

```
var lookup = new HashSet<int>(ids);
var matching = tests.Where(t => lookup.Contains(t.ID));
```

This will work even if there are duplicate IDs (again, see comments below).

Comment: Or maybe just `var lookup = new HashSet<int>(ids); var matching = tests.Where(t => lookup.ContainsKey(t.ID));`. Matching should be equivalent, but creating a `HashSet` instead of a `Dictionary` or `Lookup` should be a lot faster. -- (On my system by a factor of about three).

Comment: Also, a `HashSet` will automatically "ignore" duplicates. -- And you can filter them out for the dictionary via `var lookup = ids.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x);`

Answer (score 0):

List items = new List();

items.Find(p => p == "blah");

Should be a better way

Comment: If you can force an order on your list, you can perform a [List<T>.BinarySearch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-7.0).